# Running CLI commands from index.php entry point

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I am currently developing an application which will require me to configure and run a few administrative commands from a CLI but I would like to run it as its done on most frameworks (i.e. from the application's root folder) instead of accessing individual files.

Example in laravel

```
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectName>php artisan <command inserted here>
```

Would like mine to run the same, how are these commands identified to be redirected to the relevant handler?

Thanks

Comment: your question is not clear for me, what do you want to achieve ? what is your question ?

Comment: I would like to CLI commands similar to Artisan in Laravel where the commands are written directly from the application's root folder as opposed to accessing the individual file directly. How is that achieved??

Comment: maybe `shell_exec('cd ' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '  ; php artisan ' . $COMMAND);` ??

Comment: @HalayemAnis No I mean running commands on the application directly from the Command Prompt (cmd in Windows) not from any particular file